# flotr2 The target container must be visible at

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, flotr

I'm trying to get flotr2 graphs working in my Phonegap application. I can get their example graph(http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/documentation#usage) to run on an AVD, but if I try to use it in my actual application it gives me the error Uncaught The target container must be visible at file:///android_asset/www/flotr2.min.js:27 How would I fix this?

Code relating to flotr2:

```
//Flotr2 style contained in head below other styles
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    #container {
        width : 600px;
        height: 384px;
        margin: 8px auto;
    }
</style>
//Accidentally changing </style> to </script> causes the graph to display
//but everything else is wrong, as can be expected
```

and:

```
//Page meant to contain graph; in body
<!-- Graphs -->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page21">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Graphs
            </h3>
            <a data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide" href="#page15" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                Back
            </a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
            <div id="container"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="flotr2.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                (function () {

                    var
                        container = document.getElementById('container'),
                        start = (new Date).getTime(),
                        data, graph, offset, i;

                    // Draw a sine curve at time t
                    function animate (t) {

                        data = [];
                        offset = 2 * Math.PI * (t - start) / 10000;

                        // Sample the sine function
                        for (i = 0; i < 4 * Math.PI; i += 0.2) {
                            data.push([i, Math.sin(i - offset)]);
                        }

                        // Draw Graph
                        graph = Flotr.draw(container, [ data ], {
                            yaxis : {
                                max : 2,
                                min : -2
                            }
                        });

                        // Animate
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            animate((new Date).getTime());
                        }, 50);
                    }

                    animate(start);
                })();
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By reading the source of flotr2 you can see that in that case el.[clientWidth](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmclkbi.php) is not defined for some reason. flotr2 seems to rely on that property. Without seeing any other code it's hard to say why this happens.

### EDIT:

Since you are using PhoneGap, you could try rigging up your code to use [deviceready](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html) and see if that helps. It might be possible that clientWidth is missing since it hasn't been set up yet (the CSS hasn't loaded etc.). Anyway, worth a go.